# Multiple Prices for a product in ubercart?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

My product is a book. Each books will be sold in 3 formats.

1) Print
2) Online
3) Print + Online

All the three prices for each book will be different.

If i add the book as different product. I have to add all the content like Index, Author details etc. 3 times for each book.

Is there any way where i can allow admin to add 3 prices for each product and user can select any one of the price?

Thanks & Regards,
Satya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin is right, but there is a problem relating to the purely hardcopy version.

You have to attach a "Feature" to the product, which is the digital asset, so that when they buy they get access to the download. I believe this is for the whole product.

So, if you're wrapping them all in one product you can only offer: Online or Online and Print.
But really there is no reason to just get the print version since it doesn't cost you anything to throw in the online version.

Comment: Hi ,

Product Attributes and options allows to have the values incremented by specific amount. where as in my requirement, admin have to add all the 3 prices for all the products.

Like, book one will have the price Prints values as 100 USD and online as 30 USD and print+online price as 115 USD.

And book two will have the Print value as 200 USD and online as 42 USD and print+online as 230 USD.


Please suggest if this can be done with attributes.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do different prices with attributes... but again-- having the digital asset come with a product I don't believe is attribute dependent so you can't have a purely hard copy version with the setup you're talking about... easily.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to create 3 different products, unless the SKU is different.

You can add Attributes for this product, lets call it 'Format'. You can then add 3 options to that attribute, Print, Online, Print + Online. Then when you edit the product, you can adjust the pricing for those options (ex. Print +$10).

The cost is added to the base price of the product. So, you could make the book $0, and let these options drive the cost. Example Print $35, Online $25, Print and Online $40.

There are a couple of ways you could solve this but this is how I would probably do it.

Comment: Hi Kevin,

Product Attributes and options allows to have the values incremented by specific amount. where as in my requirement, admin have to add all the 3 prices for all the products.

Like, book one will have the price Prints values as 100 USD and online as 30 USD and print+online price as 115 USD.

And book two will have the Print value as 200 USD and online as 42 USD and print+online as 230 USD.


Please suggest if this can be done with attributes.

Answer (score 0):

satya

You can use a default general pattern for all products while building attributes and later for each product you can override it by editing the product.

For each product you can vary the range.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually set the digital portion to be attribute dependent.

1. Create an attribute called "Format" and give it your three options (Print, Online, Print and Online) with the appropriate price settings for each.
2. Add this attribute to your product.
3. You should see an "adjustments" subtab on the edit page for the product now, and here you can adjust the SKU depending on the Format that is selected.
4. On the Features tab, you can then specify the adjusted SKU's for the digital download (you may need to add the download feature twice, once for each SKU that should have it)